# gxt gwt datefield language not displayed properly

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have this date field with uibinder.

```
  <form:DateField ui:field="Importation" editable="false" allowBlank="true"/>

  private static final String    DATE_FIELD_FORMAT   = "yyyy-MMMM-dd";

  @Path("Importation")
  @UiField(provided = true)
  DateField    dImportation  = new DateField(new DateTimePropertyEditor(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FIELD_FORMAT)));
```

With this date field, I have the right format of date, it show me 2013-Septembre-04 (french), and that it is what I want.

The problem is that when I click on the little calendar, it shows almost perfecly.
Everything is in english but the button "Today" is "Aujourd'hui" like it should.

My question is how can I make the whole calendar in french: the months names and the days of the week?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the GWT locale to french and the calendar will be displayed in french. See [GWT's doc on internationalization](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html) for more info.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it wont change anything. I have checked what my locale is, it already is in french and my calendar stays halfway translated. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I know this works with "pure" GWT since I'm using it, but maybe the problem is related to GXT, which I'm not familiar with. Unfortunately, I don't have any other idea :(